# rpm says my file doesnt exist but cat will echo the file contents just fine. Why?

Tags: rpm

I'm having a ton of trouble running a simple bash script after installing my rpm-package. It keeps telling me that my files don't exist. However, when I use cat from within the script itself, the files can be read just fine. I'm very confused.

```
Name:       Test
Version:    1
Release:    1
Summary:    Test
License:    FIXME

%description
this is a test build

%install
echo "Got Here"
mkdir -m 777 %{buildroot}/tmp/
cp -a ${RPM_SOURCE_DIR}/process.sh %{buildroot}/tmp/process.sh
cp -a ${RPM_SOURCE_DIR}/hosts.csv %{buildroot}/tmp/hosts.csv

%post
echo "Running Scripts..."
cd /home/myuser/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
cat process.sh hosts.csv
echo "Done"

%files
/tmp/process.sh
/tmp/hosts.csv
```

**this line reads the contents of my files just fine:** `cat process.sh hosts.csv`

Comment: `%post` is on the target machine; your home directory won't be there. As an answer notes, installing into `/tmp` is useless.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `SourceX:` tags which tell `rpmbuild` about those files, e.g.:

```
Source0: process.sh
Source1: hosts.csv

#... 

%install
%{__install} -m755 %SOURCE0 \
    $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/path/for/process.sh
%{__install} -m0644 %SOURCE1 \
    $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/path/for/hosts.csv


%files
/path/for/process.sh
/path/for/hosts.csv
```

P.S. installing to `/tmp` makes no sense as it's typically cleared upon reboot (mounted on `tmpfs`)